# How to connect Spring to Android Studio?

Tags: android, spring

I want to use Spring (RESTful Service) as a module for my android studio project, but i cant connect spring. I want would be can to connect any spring dependencies.
I tried to download the Spring Android projects from github, however, they dont works for me.

My dependensies for the empty Android project:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '3.1.2'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.android', name: 'spring-android-rest-template', version: '1.0.1.RELEASE'
```

If i use a module, then my project doesn't see the dependencies. I also tried to connect spring without a java-module, and dependencies was visible, but i received a error:

> com.android.tools.r8.internal.nc: Sealed classes are not supported as
> program classes